# Is there a CSS selector for the first direct child only?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following html

```
<div class="section">
   <div>header</div>
   <div>
          contents
          <div>sub contents 1</div>              
          <div>sub contents 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the following style:

```
DIV.section DIV:first-child 
{
  ...
}
```

For some reason that I don't understand the style is getting applied to the *"sub contents 1"* `<div>` as well as the *"header"* `<div>`.

I thought that the selector on the style would only apply to the first direct child of a div with a class called "section".  How can I change the selector to get what I want?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joelpurra/7t5CK/

Answer (score 675, accepted):

What you posted literally means "Find any divs that are inside of section divs and are the first child of their parent." The sub contains one tag that matches that description.

It is unclear to me whether you want both children of the main div or not. If so, use this:

```
div.section > div
```

If you only want the header, use this:

```
div.section > div:first-child
```

Using the `>` changes the description to: "Find any divs that are the direct descendents of section divs" which is what you want.

Please note that all major browsers support this method, except IE6. If IE6 support is mission-critical, you will have to add classes to the child divs and use that, instead. Otherwise, it's not worth caring about.

Comment: :first-child is not required, in this case.

Comment: it seems the OP is not asking about the selector as much as why the rule is being applied to all the child divs.

Comment: My interpretation is that he gets the concept of CSS inheritance, and thought first-child would have the effect that > has. It's rather unclear wording.

Comment: Ah, the joys of being old enough to remember when the 'direct descendent' selector would solve all your problems but you couldn't use it because _it didn't work in IE_.  Much unnecessary frustration would then ensue.

Comment: It applies to the first child of the firs child also. If really need to apply the changes only on the first child we have to cancel the changes on the children of the child. Something like this: `div.section > div:first-child > div { /* Cancel Changes*/}`

Comment: This answer is wrong, it doesnt accomplish what OP is asking. @MJBZA 's answer is the correct one

Answer (score 113):

Found this question searching on Google.  This will return the first child of a element with class `container`, regardless as to what type the child is.

```
.container > *:first-child
{
}
```

Comment: The asterisk is not necessary here. `.container > :first-child` will work just as well

Answer (score 51):

CSS is called Cascading Style Sheets because the rules are inherited. Using the following selector, *will* select just the direct child of the parent, but its rules will be *inherited* by that `div`'s children `divs`:

```
div.section > div { color: red }
```

Now, both that `div` **and** its children will be `red`. You need to cancel out whatever you set on the parent if you don't want it to inherit:

```
div.section > div { color: red }
div.section > div div { color: black }
```

Now only that single `div` that is a direct child of `div.section` will be red, but its children `divs` will still be black.

Answer (score 42):

The CSS selector for the direct first-child in your case is:

```
.section > :first-child
```

The direct selector is > and the first child selector is :first-child

No need for an asterisk before the : as others suggest.  You could speed up the DOM searching by modifying this solution by prepending the tag:

```
div.section > :first-child
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `div.section > div`.

Better yet, use an `<h1>` tag for the heading and `div.section h1` in your CSS, so as to support older browsers (that don't know about the `>`) *and* keep your markup semantic.

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately I also need to support IE6, and if I use h1, I will need to set font-size to inherit so that the font matches that of the body, and ie7 and below don't support inherit.  arg!

Comment: Also, I have child divs and putting child divs in an h1 breaks the rules, even though IE renders it, I'm not sure what other browsers do

Answer (score 7):

```
div.section > div
```

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly the question asked, but maybe useful:

```
div.section > :first-child:is(div)
```

This would match only the **first child element** of .section and only if it was a div.

Match:

```
<div class="section">
  <div>MATCH</div>
  <div>NO MATCH</div>
  <div>
     <div>NO MATCH</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No match:

```
<div class="section">
  <img ... >
  <div>NO MATCH</div>
  <div>NO MATCH</div>
  <div>
     <div>NO MATCH</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved when using TailwindCSS (v3.1) with [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants).
I only wanted the first column in table to be underlined when hovered, as it is a link.

```
[&>:first-child]:hover:underline
```