# Apply :target styles to div inside target div?

Tags: html, target

Looking to apply :target styles only to div inside div with id="item1". I'm doing this so that I can use padding to get the referenced div spaced from the top of the window, but only have the styling surrounding the text (instead of having a big padding at the top that also inherits the style).

html:

```
<a href="#item1"> Item 1 </a>

<div id="item1" style="padding-top: 30px;">
<div class="I want only this div with coloured background">
  <h4>item1 title</h4>
  <p>item1 content</p> 
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
:target {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

ANSWER:

css:

```
:target > div {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}
```

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please either actually create an answer and accept it, or delete the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css selector for first direct child only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094508/css-selector-for-first-direct-child-only)

Answer (score 1):

**Extracted from the question specified by OP**

```
:target > div {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```