# Does > :first-child work whether the type is known or unknown?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have read [Is there a CSS selector for the first direct child only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094508/css-selector-for-first-direct-child-only) and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

I guess I have to apply the effect to the first-child of the `<h1>` tag, but I couldn't get it to work. So instead, I'm trying to use the `nth-child`, but still no luck.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6bthbLc/6/)**

```
<section>
<article>
    <h1>Test Details</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Layer This</li>
            <li>Layer That</li>
            <li>Layers</li>
        </ul>
</article>
</section>

<section>
    <article>
        <h1>Campaign details</h1>
        <p>Text</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
    padding:30px;
}

section article {
    background:#EBEBEB;
}

section article h1 {
    background:#0C79CB;
    padding:10px;
}

/* This is where I am struggling */
section article h1:nth-child(2):before  {
    background-color:white !important;
    content:'';
    height:10px;
    display:block;
}
```

If you open the fiddle, you'll note that the header has a blue background, and the content has a grey background. All I'm trying to do is to 'insert' a line of white:

Current:

[image]

Desired (note white between the blue and grey)

[image]

Please note, I know this is quite trivial if I just add a new `div` with a class, or even add a `border-bottom:solid 5px white;` to the `<h1>` tag, the point is I'm trying to learn about CSS selectors so is this possible using CSS Selectors?

Comment: The CSS seems totally unrelated to your request that follows. In the CSS you seem to be trying to apply a green background, but then you request a white one. And both of these are different than what your question title is asking. Please edit your question to not be contradictory. What is it that you really want to know?

Comment: You're having problems because your `h1` element doesn't have any children, so of course `nth-child` won't work on it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`:first-child` can be used with or without knowing the element type.

You can either do `parent > :first-child` to match any first child, whatever node type it is, or you can do `parent > p:first-child` to only match the first child if it's a `p` tag.

You can also do `parent > p:first-of-type` to match the first `p` inside `parent`, even if it isn't the first child.

Comment: Also, you should be using the `>` combinator, not the descendant combinator, if you actually intend to match the first child *of* "parent" and not just any element that is the first child of its parent somewhere within "parent". Otherwise, in the given markup for example, `article :first-child` will match both `article > h1:first-child` and `article > ul > li:first-child`.

Comment: This answers the title question but does not solve what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @TylerH it gives him the knowledge he needed to solve the problem on his own - probably more useful than just telling him the answer outright :-)

Comment: It gives him the knowledge of what he could have read in the spec himself, about how `first-child and `first-of-type` work, okay, great :-) But that knowledge alone isn't enough to solve the problem (see the example in the answer by Alessandro for how it differs from the desired outcome in the OP's second image). So at best it is an incomplete answer.

Comment: Sure, if you just want it handed to you on a plate without having to think then yes, the other answer gives you literal code you can cut and paste. If you're OK with having your question answered then applying that knowledge yourself, both answers are fine. You can split hairs and say "But it's not **complete**", but I don't see your issue; the OP clearly found it more than instructional enough too, just FWIW :-)

Answer (score 2):

To complete the example you are attempting using pseudo elements:

- It is possible to use `:nth-child(1)` to select the first child like `:first-child`. **Note:** In this example it is pointless, as you will only have one `<h1>` per `<article>`.
- `section article h1` is given `position: relative` and it's `position: absolute` children will be positioned in relation to it.
- The `:after` is given `position: absolute` and `width: 100%`  in order to create a line at the bottom of your `<h1>` background.

Remember that the `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements are the equivalent of:

```
<h1>
    <span>This is the :before</span>
        I am the heading
    <span>This is the :after</span>
</h1>
```

[Have an example](http://jsfiddle.net/q61kujhj/)

CSS

```
section article h1 {
    background:#0C79CB;
    padding:10px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
}
/* 
 -- Select the first h1 child of article and generate a pseudo element.
*/
 section article h1:nth-child(1):after {
    background-color:white;
    content:'';
    height:10px;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that achieves what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @TylerH - To be fair, the question title is `Does > :first-child work whether the type is known or unknown?` - my answer was meant more as an aside to Joes and possibly should have been a comment and a fiddle ;)

Comment: only after I altered it to 1. make sense, and 2. relate to the answer that OP accepted. The contents of the question clearly relate to your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you're trying to select the second child of the `h1`, but that element doesn't have any children, and so it fails. You have to select the second child of *the parent* of the `h1`

```
section article :nth-child(2):before
```

This has the advantage that you don't put any tag name in there, so it will work even if one day you'll change the `h1` to an `h2`, for example.
That last selector could be rewritten also to

```
section article :first-child:after
```

It's not **the same** thing, but you can also add generated content after an element (and in your case it'll be fine and work in the same way).

Or, if you want to match something against the `h1`, you need to target its next sibling, using the sibling selector

```
section article h1 + *:before
```

This selector will choose the first element (whatever kind it is) that appears right after an `h1`.

Or, inserting generated content after the element, you can use this

```
section article h1:after {
  background-color: white !important;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

Which, in my opinion, is the simplest thing to do