# Selecting child elements with css attribute value selector

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

i'm trying to style any .header child divs that inside any parent divs with 'recipes' as its class.

i know i can just get `.category-recipes .header` but they'll be a few parent div will change depending on where the user is. eg. 'category-recipes on category page, or 'single-page-recipes' on single posts page.

here's a simplified version of what a page looks like

```
<div class="category-recipes">

  <div class="otherdiv"></div>
  <div class="otherdiv"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>

</div> <!-- end of category -->
```

i tried it and it didnt work.

```
div[class*="recipes"] .header{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

is it possible to get a child or parent in with this kind of selector?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by there will be few divs? Where are those? They won't be affected in your current markup if you use `.category-recipes .header`

Comment: you have not closed div

Comment: @ManojKumar on different pages, the parent class would be different. 
eg. single-page-recipes , category-recipes etc

Comment: @Dmitriy just a typo error when i was typing this question but its fine on my code.

Comment: use an id for header and recipes as a class

Comment: I guess he uses WordPress and not static HTML

Comment: [Your `div[class*="recipes"]` selector works fine...](http://jsbin.com/qucumopebi/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x25yo75s/

Comment: strangely it only worked when i changed it to id instead of using classes like what @RachelGallen said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: https://jsfiddle.net/09zkqatx/

Basically, I've done all the same way you described.

```
div div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div[class*="recipes"] .header{
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, not quite sure whats wrong with mine but it worked with

div[id*="recipes"] .archive-header{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

had to change the div from using a class to id

Answer (score 0):

```
div[class*="recipes"] div[class*="header"]{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Is a spin off of what I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094554/4871483

You could just use JavaScript and select like this

```
var parDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("category-recipes");
for(parDiv in parDivs){
    var child = parDiv.children[2];
}
```

And change the style from JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want-
Use a separate *common class* for 'recipes'
For example,

```
<div class="category-recipes recipes">
  <div class="otherdiv"></div>
  <div class="otherdiv"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
</div> <!-- end of category -->
```

And also for your 'single-page-recipes',

```
<div class="single-page-recipes recipes">
  <div class="otherdiv"></div>
  <div class="otherdiv"></div>
  <div class="header"></div>
</div> <!-- end of single page -->
```

For the above codes, use the css -

```
div.recipes > div.header {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

***OR***, if you can't add a common class, you can use small JS snippet to achieve this -

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0];
// first check if the parent node has class with text recipes
if(el.parentNode.classList.toString().match(/recipes/)) {
    //get the first child with class header and then style it
    el.style.marginBottom = "40px"; 
}
```

check out the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xLzagpmv/4/