# CSS selector for first element without class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to css and I have some **auto generated snippet** as following,

```
<div id="display">
  <div>
      <div>
        <p>red</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>not red</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have attached auto generated element into display div (first div) through javascript snippet.
I want to **select only first paragraph** using CSS.

I tried following CSS also tried **nth-child(1)** ,

```
p:first-child {
    color:red;
}
```

But it's selecting both of the values.

Comment: `#display > div > div:first-child p:first-child`

Comment: yes, that's the issue I'm facing here. Those all those auto generated divs only contains same height, width and positions. Which I have added into sample for simplicity

Comment: @jbutler483 Thanks you for quick working solution. Could you please point me to understand  concept of '>' ?

Comment: You may accept @Barmar 's solution as it does the same thing

Comment: That is the *direct child* operator. So will target a div immediately contained within the parent `#display`. A good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094512/3436942)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `<p>` elements are the first child of their respective parent DIVs. You want the `<p>` that's the child of the first child DIV.

```css
div:first-child > p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>red</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>not red</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `first-of-type` also to achieve that goal

```css
 div:first-of-type > p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>red</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>not red</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#display > div > div:first-child > p{ color: red }